# Teradata and SQL migration. How do I migrate SQL and teradata?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, teradata

I have a database of millions records. I need a database setup to make it easy to extract data for data analysis.For now I am using SQL. I have downloaded Teradata Studio. But how do I connect to existing database server from Teradata? Or migrate sql database on teradata?

Comment: Consider asking this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Teradata SQL Assistant is a SQL Client, not a database. It is merely a client to connect to a database (you can connect it to your SQL server via and ODBC connection and a DSN on your computer that utilizes that ODBC connection). I assume this isn't want you want to do though. You want to move your data to a Teradata Database, but you will have to get a Teradata Database and then migrate your data from your SQL server which you can do with the Teradata TTU suite and it's included tools like Teradata Parallel Transporter, Mload, or Fastload utilities.